# Android java app main activity blank after 2nd run fo app

Tags: java, android

I am working on some [Android](https://developer.android.com/about) application using `Java` using [Android Studio](https://developer.android.com/studio) on `Windows 10` operating system. I have single [Activity](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity) with several [Fragments](https://developer.android.com/guide/fragments?gclid=CjwKCAjwg5uZBhATEiwAhhRLHj4fU25s1tPqur0DDKHzJ2nxwP_RprJeDkiEpzOJR_EjsYXv_GWTWRoCIu4QAvD_BwE&gclsrc=aw.ds). Now, if I use **target mobile phone with no previous installation of this app** or I **uninstall the app on target mobile phone**, the `main activity` shows correct contents (`Login Fragment`):
[image: Correct login screen]
However on *2nd* and all other runs from *Android Studio*, I get blanck black screen from `main activity`:
[image: Blank activity]
Like I said, if I uninstall app or use the phone with no previous installation of app, it works fine. What is the problem?

P.S.: Since I am rather newbie with Android and I have no clue at all, what is wrong, I did not post any code of mine, becuase I do not know at all if this is a bug in my code or something else ...

**UPDATE 1**

According to @Ashutosh Ojha and @bhaskarkh hints, here is the method for switching fragments inside `MainActivity.java`:

```
public void switchToScreen(final Fragment targetFragment)
{
    this.getSupportFragmentManager()
        .beginTransaction()
        .replace(R.id.mainActivity,
            targetFragment)
        .commit();
}
```

And here is relevant part of `MainActivity.java`:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity
{
    private static final String TAG=MainActivity.class.getSimpleName();
    
    private LoginFragment loginFragment=null;    
    
    private static final String[] appMandatoryPermissions=new String[]
    {
        Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE,
        Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE,
        Manifest.permission.CAMERA
    };
    
        @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        
        if(this.loginFragment==null)
        {
            this.loginFragment=LoginFragment.newInstance();
        }
        
        this.checkAppPermissions();
    }
    
    public void switchToScreen(final Fragment targetFragment)
    {
        this.getSupportFragmentManager()
            .beginTransaction()
            .replace(R.id.mainActivity,
                targetFragment)
            .commit();
    }
    
    public void checkAppPermissions()
    {
        int permissionGrantResult=0;
        List<String> neededPermissionsList=new ArrayList<>();

        for(String permission:MainActivity.appMandatoryPermissions)
        {
            permissionGrantResult=ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this.getApplicationContext(),
                permission);

            if(permissionGrantResult!=PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED)
            {
                neededPermissionsList.add(permission);
            }
        }

        if(!neededPermissionsList.isEmpty())
        {
            ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this,
                neededPermissionsList.toArray(new String[neededPermissionsList.size()]),
                0);
        }
    }
    
        @Override
    public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode,
        @NonNull String[] permissions,
        @NonNull int[] grantResults)
    {
        boolean allPermissionsGranted=false;

        super.onRequestPermissionsResult(requestCode,
            permissions,
            grantResults);

        if((permissions.length>0)&&
            (grantResults.length>0)&&
            (permissions.length==grantResults.length))
        {
            for(int permissionIndex=0; permissionIndex<permissions.length; permissionIndex++)
            {
                if(grantResults[permissionIndex]==PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED)
                {
                    Toast.makeText(this,
                            permissions[permissionIndex]+
                                " "+
                                "granted",
                            Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)
                        .show();

                    allPermissionsGranted=true;
                }
                else if(grantResults[permissionIndex]==PackageManager.PERMISSION_DENIED)
                {
                    Toast.makeText(this,
                            permissions[permissionIndex]+
                                " "+
                                "denied",
                            Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)
                        .show();

                    allPermissionsGranted=false;
                }
                else
                {
                    Toast.makeText(this,
                            permissions[permissionIndex]+
                                " "+
                                "invalid value, aborting",
                            Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)
                        .show();

                    allPermissionsGranted=false;
                }
            }
        }

        if(allPermissionsGranted)
        {
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
            this.switchToScreen(this.loginFragment);
        }
        else
        {
            this.finishAndRemoveTask();
        }
    }
```

Is [this.finishAndRemoveTask();](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity#finishAndRemoveTask()) right way to quit app?
And here is `LoginFragment.java`:

```
package com.mikroelektronika.guestnotificationsystem.Main;

import android.annotation.SuppressLint;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.Toast;

import androidx.annotation.NonNull;
import androidx.fragment.app.Fragment;

import com.mikroelektronika.R;
import com.mikroelektronika.guestnotificationsystem.MainActivity;

public class LoginFragment extends Fragment
{
    private static final String TAG=LoginFragment.class.getSimpleName();

    private Button btnLogin=null;
    private Button btnClear=null;
    private Button btnRegister=null;
    private EditText userNameEntryField=null;
    private EditText passwordEntryField=null;

    @NonNull
    public static LoginFragment newInstance()
    {
        LoginFragment fragment=new LoginFragment();
        Bundle args=new Bundle();

        fragment.setArguments(args);

        return fragment;
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    }

    @SuppressLint("SetTextI18n")
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(@NonNull LayoutInflater inflater,
        ViewGroup container,
        Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        View inflatedView=inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_login,
            container,
            false);

        if(this.userNameEntryField==null)
        {
            this.userNameEntryField=(EditText)inflatedView.findViewById(R.id.editUsername_field);
            this.userNameEntryField.setText("my@bla.com");
        }

        if(this.passwordEntryField==null)
        {
            this.passwordEntryField=(EditText)inflatedView.findViewById(R.id.editPassword_field);
            this.passwordEntryField.setText("frgfdgghgfhgy");
        }

        if(this.btnLogin==null)
        {
            this.btnLogin=(Button)inflatedView.findViewById(R.id.btnLogin);
        }

        if(this.btnClear==null)
        {
            this.btnClear=(Button)inflatedView.findViewById(R.id.btnClear);
        }

        if(this.btnRegister==null)
        {
            this.btnRegister=(Button)inflatedView.findViewById(R.id.btnRegister);
        }

        this.btnLogin.setOnClickListener(v->
        {
            String username=userNameEntryField.getText().toString();
            String password=passwordEntryField.getText().toString();

            if(!username.isEmpty()&&
                !password.isEmpty())
            {
                MainActivity mainActivity=(MainActivity)requireActivity();

                mainActivity.userLogin(username,
                    password);
            }
            else
            {
                Toast.makeText(getContext(),
                    "Credentials cannot be empty.",
                    Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        });

        this.btnClear.setOnClickListener(v->
        {
            userNameEntryField.setText("");
            passwordEntryField.setText("");
        });

        this.btnRegister.setOnClickListener(v->
        {
            MainActivity mainActivity=(MainActivity)requireActivity();

            mainActivity.switchToScreen(mainActivity.getRegisterFragment());
        });

        return inflatedView;
    }
}
```

And its `XML counterpart`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@color/black"
    tools:context=".guestnotificationsystem.Main.LoginFragment">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textViewGreetings"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:text="@string/welcome_text"
        android:textAlignment="center" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textViewUsername"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/textViewGreetings"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:text="@string/username_text"
        android:textAlignment="center" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/editUsername_field"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/textViewUsername"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:autofillHints=""
        android:ems="40"
        android:importantForAutofill="no"
        android:inputType="textEmailAddress"
        android:minHeight="48dp"
        android:text=""
        tools:ignore="SpeakableTextPresentCheck" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textViewPassword"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/editUsername_field"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:text="@string/password_text"
        android:textAlignment="center" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/editPassword_field"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/textViewPassword"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:autofillHints=""
        android:ems="40"
        android:importantForAutofill="no"
        android:inputType="textPassword"
        android:minHeight="48dp"
        android:text=""
        tools:ignore="SpeakableTextPresentCheck" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/layoutButtons"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/editPassword_field"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:minHeight="48dp"
        android:orientation="horizontal">

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/btnLogin"
            style="?android:attr/buttonBarButtonStyle"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:text="@string/login_text" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/btnClear"
            style="?android:attr/buttonBarButtonStyle"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:text="@string/clear_text" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/layoutButtons"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:minHeight="48dp"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/btnRegister"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:minHeight="48dp"
            android:text="@string/register_text" />
    </LinearLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: By  using  debugger can you  confirm if this black fragment is your  LoignFragment or any other ? What I think is on 2nd time run you are opening any new Fragment or on basis of some condition your LoginFragment content is not visible

Comment: Add some code or logs to get more idea we cant help without seeing the code.

Comment: @AshutoshOjha I've updated the question - added relevant code.

Comment: @bhaskarkh I've updated the question - added relevant code.

Comment: When  you are running  app 2nd time you had already provided permission  and there is no fragment or UI  loading in this case hence blank screen

Comment: if(!neededPermissionsList.isEmpty())
        {
            ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this,
                neededPermissionsList.toArray(new String[neededPermissionsList.size()]),
                0);
        }else{//call setContentView() and  fragment  loading here}    .    The way  you are managing this fragment  transaction is  incorrect, it can be optimised . Search for a better way  to do this permission check  and  fragment transaction

Comment: @AshutoshOjha yes indeed, missed that! Thank you, could you upgrade to answer and so I can upvote?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you are running app 2nd time you had already provided permission and there is no fragment or UI loading in this case hence blank screen. Else case is missing after  permission check

```
  if(!neededPermissionsList.isEmpty())
  {
    ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this,
    neededPermissionsList.toArray(new 
    String[neededPermissionsList.size()]),0);
    }
    else{ //call setContentView and  FragmentTransaction here}
```

NOTE: You can have  more optimised  way of doing your task, please check that